# Retrofit URL not being translated correctly

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit to make calls to an API. I added an interceptor to view the url being requested. In debug releases, the url is translated correctly, but signed releases causes the url to not be translated and parsed as it should. Some relevant code is below:

Retrofit service:

```
@GET("/1.1/launch/next/{number}")
Observable<LaunchResponse> getNextXLaunches(@Path("number") int numberOfNextLaunches);
```

When calling this method, I simply pass in an integer to determine the number of launches to request. In signed apks, the above produces the following URL:

`..../1.1/launch/next/%7BlaunchNum%7D`

instead of

`..../1.1/launch/next/10`

As you can see, the value passed into the path is not being translated correctly, and instead `{number}` is being resolved literally.

I have tried different versions after coming across similar issues:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
```

What I find odd is this issue is only present when running a signed release apk. What might be causing this issue? What's the fix?

**EDIT:** As requested, here are some relevant proguard rules:

```
# Retrofit 2.X
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

# OkHttp
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

# OkHttp3
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

**EDIT:** I've built a release with `minifyEnabled` set to `false` to disable ProGuard, and it worked correctly. Therefore, the issue must be with my ProGuard configuration, though I am unsure of what it could be.

Comment: are you using progaurd?

Comment: Yes. Retrofit, OkHttp, and OkHttp3 are all added to my proguard rules.

Comment: can you add your progaurd rules?

Comment: Added relevant proguard rules.

Comment: Did you try `String.valueOf(numberOfNextLaunches)`?

Comment: Whether `numberOfNextLaunches` is an `int` or a `String` is irrelevant.

Comment: `@Path` should not be an `int` but it should be a `String`.

Comment: @AmrutBidri That's incorrect, an `int` is used in some of the examples on the Retrofit site: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I fixed the issue. After updating the relevant dependencies and narrowing it down to a problem with my ProGuard configuration, I added the following rules to my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
# Retrofit 2.X
...
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Note: had already been added when updating to OkHttp 3.
# OkHttp3
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

In addition, several local files were not being kept. Including those in the rules explicitly or making sure you are using a wildcard to keep all local files should resolve the issue:

```
#local
-keep class example.** { *; }
```

Comment: There is a 2 day waiting period before you can accept self answers.

Comment: oops, sorry, then!